# How to implement google Authenticator In ASP.NET 4 webforms?

Tags: c#, webforms, .net-4.0, google-authenticator

I want to implement two factor authentication using google authenticator in asp.net webform for .NET 4 framework .

Anyone knows the code please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look here

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/google-authenticator-in-asp-net

You will find how to implement 2FA authentication in your ASP.NET web application using Google Authenticator app